# Phase shift of sin and cos

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: For how many values of $n$ with $0\le n\le 100$ is the graph of $f(x) = \sin (x + n)$ identical to the graph of $g(x) = \cos x$?

Here, I realized that the phase shift of $f(x)$ is $n$ left from the $\sin$ function. To get the cosine function by phase-shifting the sine function, the phase shift must be $\frac{\pi}{2}+2x\pi$. Therefore, I realized that $n$ must be in this form, with the smallest value as $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and the largest value as $\frac{63\pi}{2}$, which gives $32$ values for $n$.

However, this answer is incorrect. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the values of $n$? (For instance, is $n$ assumed to be an integer?)

Comment: Not that I am aware of. None of the resulting values for n would be integers.

Answer (score 2):

It's correct that $\cos(x) = \sin\left(x + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and $\sin(x) = \sin(x + 2k\pi)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and that therefore $$
  \cos(x) = \sin(x + d) \Leftrightarrow d = \tfrac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi,\, k \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

But then you went astray. Requiring that $0 \leq d \leq 100$ yields $$
  0 \leq \tfrac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi \leq 100 \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq k \leq \frac{100- \frac{\pi}{2}}{2\pi} = \frac{50}{\pi} - \frac{1}{4} \approx 15.7
$$
Since we need $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, that implies $k \in \{0,1,\ldots,15\}$, and therefore $$
  \cos(x) = \sin(x + n),\, 0 \leq d \leq 100 \Leftrightarrow d \in \left\{\tfrac{\pi}{2} + 0\cdot 2\pi , \tfrac{\pi}{2} + 1\cdot 2\pi, \ldots, \tfrac{\pi}{2} + 15\cdot 2\pi\right\} \text{,}
$$
i.e. that are $16$ possible $d$.

Note that I wrote $d$, not $n$, because it's often implicitly assumed that a quantity called $n$ is an integer. But none of the possible values for $d$ *are* integers, so if $n$ is supposed to be an integer, the answer is zero.